# Operation not permitted(1)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am doing an iphone app, were my code works fine with out any error, but when i build the code its failing. and i am getting an error like

> rsync: rename "/Users/pcmac/Desktop/Digidrive(IPhone)/Build/RestKit/Support/.svn/.format.0FKOPh" -> "RestKit/Support/.svn/format": Operation not permitted (1)

I am getting this error many at a time and finally says:

```
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23
```

Can anyone give me solution to solve this ?

Comment: Did you check the file permissions on .svn/format.OFKOPh?

Comment: hi frank i cannot find the file with this name in my project folder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've added RestKit via Subversion (SVN). Is this really what you want? Why not get this dependency from [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) or donwload it from [RestKit.org](http://restkit.org) as a source package?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect the file permissions on .svn/.format.OFKOPh; to check them:

- open a terminal window
- change to the .svn dir:
    cd /Users/pcmac/Desktop/Digidrive(IPhone)/Build/RestKit/Support/.svn/
- check permissions:
    ls -la .format*
- if the permissions are wrong (i.e. you are not allowed to move the file):

  chmod 644 .format.OFKOPh